# Как на Яндекс Контесте посмотреть правильный ответ на тесте, где выводится ошибка?

Tags: яндекс-контест

Можно ли вообще на яндекс контесте(именно задачи для собеседования) посмотреть правильный ответ на тесте, где выводится ошибка? просто я не понимаю, каким образом я должен найти ошибку в алгоритме, если ответ неверен аж на 55-ом тесте, и при этом не написан ни мой ответ, ни тот ответ, который должен был получиться.

Comment: `я не понимаю, каким образом я должен найти ошибку в алгоритме` - проверяйте граничные случаи, проверяйте разные данные на входе вашего алгоритма, пишите для него тесты самостоятельно тоже.

Comment: Вообще говоря - думать. Именно в этом и хитрость соревнования - иначе все было бы гораздо проще... На каждом шагу своего решения думайте, как бы его *сломать*? Какие данные - отвечающие условию задачи - могут заставить ваш алгоритм работать неверно?

Comment: @Harry Но при этом на codeforces, например, показывают тот тест, на котором вышла ошибка. Хотя там тоже соревнование.

Comment: `и при этом не написан ни мой ответ, ни тот ответ, который должен был получиться` - добро пожаловать в жестокую реальность. Радуйтесь, что вам хотя бы сообщают о самом факте существования такого набора входных данных, на котором ваш алгоритм даёт неверный ответ :D В реальной практике некому будет преподнести все ошибки алгоритма вам на блюдечке.